# python - imagegrab module returns error when using bbox

Tags: python

my image grabber returns an error

```py
ID = randint(111111, 999999)
#Make screenshot and crop on coordinates 162, 187, 91, 206
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(162, 187, 91, 206))
im.save(os.getcwd() + ID + ".png", "PNG")
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DIRECTORY", line 25, in <module>
    TextToImage()
  File "DIRECTORY", line 13, in TextToImage
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(162, 187, 91, 206))
  File "DIRECTORY", line 28, in grab
    raise ValueError("bbox x2<=x1")
ValueError: bbox x2<=x1
```

Help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: The bbox is a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

The bbox needs something like **(top_left_x, top_left_y, bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y)**. This could be interpreted as **[(point A), (pointB)]** where point A is smaller than point B. I had a problem with this myself while creating a bbox using the users mouse coordinates. Sometimes the user introduced right_bottom first and caused an error. To solve it I simply compared tuples before adding them.

```py
    if tuple(B) < tuple(A):
        ordered_tuples = list(B) + list(A)
    else:
        ordered_tuples = list(A) + list(B)
    bbox = tuple(ordered_tuples)
```

My implementation was different but you should get the point.